# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence numpy

Tags: python, numpy, valueerror

This is my code:

X: A numpy array of shape (num_test, D) containing test data

dists: A numpy array of shape (num_test, num_train) where dists[i, j] is the Euclidean distance between the ith test point and the jth training point.

```
  def compute_distances_two_loops(self, X):
    num_test = X.shape[0]
    num_train = self.X_train.shape[0]
    dists = np.zeros((num_test, num_train))
    print(num_test,num_train)
    for i in range(num_test):
      for j in range(num_train):
        dists[i,j] = np.sqrt((np.pow(X[i],2) + np.pow(self.X_train[j],2))                
    return dists
```

I am getting the following error:
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Comment: What are all of these variables supposed to hold

Comment: This question needs a lot of work

Comment: And where are you using scipy? You tagged that, as well as some other questionable tags

Comment: @RushabhMehta- Please, see the edit.

Comment: Examine this calculation: `np.sqrt((np.pow(X[i],2) + np.pow(self.X_train[j],2))`.  Pay attention to `type`, `shape` and `dtype`?  To fit in `dists[i,j]` is has to be a scalar or array with 1 element, e.g. `shape` (1,).  `X[i]` is a row of `X`, a 1d with shape (D,).  Similarly `X_trains[j]`.  And you haven't done anything to reduce those arrays (or the 'outer' sum) to a scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula for computing the distance is wrong.

Try changing this line:

```
dists[i,j] = np.sqrt((np.pow(X[i],2) + np.pow(self.X_train[j],2))
```

to this:

```
dists[i,j] = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.pow(X[i] - self.X_train[j], 2)))
```

or this:

```
dists[i,j] = np.linalg.norm(X[i] - X_train[j])
```

or perhaps just replace the entire thing with this:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def compute_distances(self, X):
    return cdist(X, X_train)
```